# Transform pandas DataFrame with group results

Tags: python, pandas

Hey I'm searching for a pandas solution of getting result from groups of a DataFrame, and then applying these results to the complete dataframe. Here is a minimal example of what I'm doing right now, but I dont find it very good.

```
import pandas as np
data = [[0.0, 2.4285714285714286, '0', 'mica02', 'd2o'],
         [10.0, 1.4285714285714286, '225', 'mica02', 'd2o'],
         [13.0, 1.0833333333333333, '225', 'mica02', 'd2o'],
         [954.0, 5.420454545454546, '225', 'mica02', 'air'],
         [937.0, 5.162534435261708, '225', 'mica02', 'air'],
         [75.0, 0.4966887417218543, '225', 'mica02', 'h2o'],
         [78.0, 0.49523809523809526, '225', 'mica02', 'h2o'],
        [80.0, 0.49323809523809526, '225', 'mica01', 'h2o'],
       ]
df0 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['basesubed', 'normalized', 'rot', 'm0', 'm1'])
df0
```

gives and this is a cut down version of what I'm working with:

```
    basesubed   normalized  rot     m0  m1
0   0.0     2.428571    0   mica02  d2o
1   10.0    1.428571    225     mica02  d2o
2   13.0    1.083333    225     mica02  d2o
3   954.0   5.420455    225     mica02  air
4   937.0   5.162534    225     mica02  air
5   75.0    0.496689    225     mica02  h2o
6   78.0    0.495238    225     mica02  h2o
7   80.0    0.493238    225     mica01  h2o
```

Now, group the DataFrame by `m0` and `rot` metadata and calculate something from the group. Lets say median for now:

```
mask = (df0.m1 == 'h2o') 
gdf = df0[mask].groupby(['m0', 'rot']).median()
gdf

        basesubed   normalized  basesubed_n     normalized_n
m0  rot                 
mica01  225     80.0    0.493238    1.0     1.0
mica02  225     76.5    0.495963    1.0     1.0
```

Now I want to subtract the result from my original DataFrame, but only when the multiindex of the `gdf` matches the metadata in `df0` so I do:

```
for i in range(len(gdf.index.values)):
    mask = ((df0.m0 == gdf.index.values[i][0]) & (df0.rot == gdf.index.values[i][1]))
    df0.loc[mask, 'basesubed_n'] = df0[mask]['basesubed'] / gdf.loc[gdf.index.values[i]].basesubed
    df0.loc[mask, 'normalized_n'] = df0[mask]['normalized'] / gdf.loc[gdf.index.values[i]].normalized
df0
```

and I get:

```
    basesubed   normalized  rot     m0  m1  basesubed_n     normalized_n
0   0.0     2.428571    0   mica02  d2o     NaN     NaN
1   10.0    1.428571    225     mica02  d2o     0.130719    2.880397
2   13.0    1.083333    225     mica02  d2o     0.169935    2.184301
3   954.0   5.420455    225     mica02  air     12.470588   10.929142
4   937.0   5.162534    225     mica02  air     12.248366   10.409103
5   75.0    0.496689    225     mica02  h2o     0.980392    1.001462
6   78.0    0.495238    225     mica02  h2o     1.019608    0.998538
7   80.0    0.493238    225     mica01  h2o     1.000000    1.000000
```

Note how the first row got NaN because it had no matching entry in gdf. This is exactly what I want, because there was no `rot=0` and `m1=h2o` in `df0`. This mismatch is also the reason, why I couldn't find a solution, that used `df.groupby().transform()` because it also didn't match the shape of the data frame I wanted to aplly it to.

Any help would be apricieated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about the `transform` method you want to use, but you can use `merge` to prevent your loop `for`. Here is an idea:

```
# gdf is slightly different, just reset indexes to merge on them later
gdf = df0[mask].groupby(['m0', 'rot']).median().reset_index()
# merge df0 with gdf on the two columns 'm0', 'rot'
df0 = df0.merge(gdf, on = ['m0',  'rot'], how = 'left', suffixes = ('','_median'))
# now you can calculate the column _n such as:
df0['basesubed_n'] = df0['basesubed'] / df0['basesubed_median']
df0['normalized_n'] = df0['normalized'] / df0['normalized_median']
# finally, drop the columns _median
df0 = df0.drop(['basesubed_median','normalized_median'],1)
```

And you get the same output than yours

EDIT: Actually, I found the answer with `transform`, just do:

```
df0[['basesubed_n','normalized_n']] = df0.groupby(['m0', 'rot'])\
                                         .transform(lambda x: x/x[mask].median())
```

Comment: Year, that works :) Thx a lot. So the trick was to put the mask into the transform, that was what I dit wrong. Thx a lot.